# To what degree do min-cuts specify the cut function of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, algorithms

Given an unweighted graph $G = (V, E)$, let the cut function on this graph be defined to be: 
$C:2^V \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that:
$$C_G(S) = |\{(u,v) \in E : u \in S \wedge v \not\in S\}|$$

For any two vertices $i,j \in V$, let the $(i,j)$ min-cut in a graph $G$ be: 
$$\alpha_{i,j}(G) = \min_{S \subset V : i \in S, j \not \in S}C_G(S)$$
Now, suppose we have two unweighted graphs on the same vertex set, $G = (V,E)$ and $H = (V,E')$ such that they are identical with respect to all $(i,j)$ min-cuts:
$$\forall i,j \in V, \alpha_{i,j}(G) = \alpha_{i,j}(H)$$
How much can $H$ and $G$ differ with respect to their cuts? That is, how large can the following quantity be:
$$\Delta(H,G) = \max_{S \subset V} |C_G(S) - C_H(S)|$$

Note that if the graphs are allowed to be weighted (or to be multigraphs), then for any $G$, there is a tree $T$ that agrees with $G$ on all min-cuts (A Gomory-Hu tree). But I am interested in the case of unweighted graphs...

Comment: I love how it's "function of a graph" instead of "graph of a function"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If G and H are graphs with n vertices, Δ(G,H) can be Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Here is an example which shows this.  Let n=4k+1 be a prime.  Define two graphs G=(V,E) and H=(V,E′) by V={0,1,2,…,4k}, E = {{i,j} | 1 ≤ ((j−i) mod n) ≤ k}, E′ = {{i,j} | k+1 ≤ ((j−i) mod n) ≤ 2k}.  Note that G and H are both unions of k edge-disjoint Hamiltonian circuits, which implies that α<sub>i,j</sub>(G)=α<sub>i,j</sub>(H)=2k for any distinct i and j.  Let S={0,1,2,…,2k−1}.  Then Δ(G,H) ≥ C<sub>H</sub>(S)−C<sub>G</sub>(S) = k(3k+1)−k(k+1) = 2k<sup>2</sup> = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

There is no reason to believe that this is the maximum of Δ(G,H) for given n, but it is obviously optimal up to a constant factor.